# What stopped the lightsaber from hitting Cal and Cere?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, star-wars-jedi-fallen-order

The final showdown in the video game *Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order* has a moment when a lightsaber is about to hit Cere and Cal but the blade seems to stop short of its intended targets, as if encountering an unseen forcefield.

Now previously in the game, Cal *is* saved by a forcefield but that forcefield is visible and we see how it got there (BD-1 turned it on to save Cal). But in this final showdown there's no clear reason for a forcefield to suddenly activate.

What am I missing?

Comment: here's a clip of what I mean [spoilers in video] https://youtu.be/oX7Y7Roz_iU?t=285

Comment: Isn't that just Cere blocking it / creating a (literal) force field with the force?

Answer (score 5):

As Y7vc said in the comments, this is not a force field as such.

Cere is blocking/holding the blade with the force. She is struggling with her emotions at this point, on the precipice between light and dark and is fairly strong in the force so its definitely something she is capable of.

Comment: So she created a force field with the Force? Is that even a Force power?

Comment: It is a Force power, basically a Force Push that just matches the strength of the swing to stop it and focusing only on the blade/arm instead of the whole body. It's showing the strength of the attacker, because Cere is using all her strength and can barely hold back the attack. It's not really a force field because a trooper could have walked up and fired, hitting her with no resistance.

Comment: It’s the most basic use of the Force, using the Force to move or stop something from moving.  It was nice before people started thinking every possible use of the Force needed to be a separate ‘power’.  Something that only really became a thing because stuff like video games could not work in their mechanics/programming without defined powers.

Comment: @RedCaio https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_barrier if you need similar moments where something like it was used.